# How to add sub menus into context menu in Nattable?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, nattable

I am using Nattable in my application. I have built a context menu which popups on right click on any row in the nattable.Now I would like to add sub menu items for one of the menu item in the context menu. Is it possible to add sub menus into context menu in Nattable ?

This is how I have constructed context menu,
Creating context menu using PopupMenuBuilder class and Binding context menu into Nattable by extending AbstractUiBindingConfiguration class.

Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: How are you constructing the context menu?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Creating context menu using PopupMenuBuilder class and Binding context menu into Nattable by extending AbstractUiBindingConfiguration class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no build-in support for sub-menus. But as you basically create the menus programmatically by using the `AbstractUiBindingConfiguration` you can also programmatically add the sub-menu items this way. Typically by using the `SWT.CASCADE` style bit on the `MenuItem` and setting a `Menu` to that `MenuItem`.

Creating sub-menus programmatically is shown in this [SWT Snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet238.java)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer! I would check the solution that you provided.